# How can I find iframe instance within minified JS files?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, minifiedjs

I am looking for iframe usages in our project minified JS folders. There are a bunch of references to iframes in folders that don't use iframes. Is there a definitive string I should be looking for?

Comment: Why don't you search from the developement code instead? Or are you searching for  some possibly injected code?

Comment: The projects consists of many other projects in the form of npm packages. Not possible to look into every single repo because there are so many

Comment: This is a very complex web app with a desktop app. I don't even have credentials to go into every page. Inspecting will be impossible